# Where can I watch Seiyuu shows?

Tags: resources, voice-acting

By Seiyuu shows I mean things like Hanazawa Kana's Hanazawa Kana Hitori de Dekiru kana, Matsuoka Yoshitsugu's Matsuoka Restaurant.

Is there anywhere where one can watch them completely with consistent quality? I can find them in YouTube but it was the one uploaded by some random guy on the internet. The quality also varies greatly, like some only have voice, some with only low res video, and it also miss some chapters (i.e incomplete).

Note 1: limit answer to legal sources.
Note 2: not limited to the said shows. They are just examples.

Comment: Important question: since you're looking for legal, high-quality source, is Japanese site okay?

Comment: @AkiTanaka of course

Comment: i assume if it doesn't matter if it has english subs or not?

Comment: @Memor-X yes. Preferably with one since shows like Uchida Maaya's one where her brother Yuuma came as guest can be hard to follow due to them talking very fast. But it's okay even without subs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hanazawa Kana's Hanazawa Kana Hitori de Dekiru kana*:
You can listen to this radio program on Thursday, 23:00-23:30 Japan time, by visiting the following URL: https://www.uniqueradio.jp/form/form5.php.

This channel is legal under Japanese law.
I don't know if it's accessible from outside Japan.
You will be asked in Japanese where you live, your occupation, and your address. There is no option to choose an address outside of Japan, but you may choose Tokyo.

---

The [*Onsen*](https://www.onsen.ag/) (Japanese) is another well-known channel that offers voice actor's programs, but I don't know if it's accessible from outside of Japan.

At least the following YouTube channels are legal under Japanese domestic law. As these are YouTube channels, they can be accessed from outside of Japan.
These are provided by the holder of the official content.

- [Dengeki Bunko Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoIkccJcBM1MBJEgQ4p5p7Q)
- [TrySail official YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuI2in6tTAjsaqzdeOeWZkQ)
- [Second Shot Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4goPtB-z_4vh3WQ37HZ-nw)
- [Phonon Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/PhononSeiyu)
- [YOUDEAL LIVE Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfcVWrzB6l9xJaL4Vo-3IOw)
- [GA Bunko Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43H8s_LItL4ppe6-STQBSA)
- [GAGAGAch!!!](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxj11Tw-oDm6m8eet3TT7XQ)
- [warnerbrosanime](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcjqSFXBg2cGQg5r0YooMiA)
- [ANIPLEX](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC14QT5j2nQI8lKBCGtrrBQA)
- [Hi★Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHA7Yni3ULg)
- [Bushiload](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcjqSFXBg2cGQg5r0YooMiA)
- [NBC Universal Anime/Music](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeOMz8AiNhsDhEovu5_3ujQ)
- [KING AMUSEMENT CREATIVE](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCR61XV4ROXhkcfLO31hTGuw)
- [Anime Channel by FuRyu](https://www.youtube.com/user/FuryuAnimeChannel)

For some content it seems to be possible to use Youtube's automatic subtitle generation.

Some of above content providers are American companies, but the contents are related to Japanimation.

Some channels seem to have special sub-channels. For example, the [NBC Universal's](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeOMz8AiNhsDhEovu5_3ujQ) channel, has the [*Gochiusa*'s channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4nFt-n9J3Q4DQSSvB0DR6g) as a sub-channel.　The operation of such a subchannel may be limited to when the program they want to promote (like *Gochiusa*) are on the air.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, seiyuu shows/events falls into a few categories

- Shows, events, Internet radio related to anime.

  When it doesn't make economic sense to sell the event on a separate BD/DVD, these are included in the original BD/DVD of the anime. WORKING!! series, Oregairu series, High School DxD series, Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann are a few examples of this category. Unfortunately, most of these contents don't make it to any of the international release, so most of the time, the only option to view them legally is to import the BD/DVD from Japan.

  There are some cases, such as [Matsuoka Yoshitsugu's Matsuoka Restaurant](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B011HE19BG/) series, or [Tesagure Bukatsumono Bangaihen](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B017SPIRY0/), where it's marketable on its own and comes in a separate BD/DVD. These are even more unlikely to be licensed outside Japan, so the only legal option is to import BD/DVD from Japan.  [K-ON! Live Events](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003FGI1G6) are pretty much among the few exceptions that enjoy Western release.

  Internet radio related to the series are occasionally bundled in the limited edition of original BD/DVD. Other time, they are sold separately. I don't know of any Internet radio CD ever localized to be sold outside Japan.
- Shows or events (live) streamed on [NicoNico](http://live.nicovideo.jp/)

  These days, many anime events are live streamed on NicoNico. However, most of them are geo-locked to Japan, so there is little chance that you can watch anything you want outside of Japan. If you are in Japan, it's possible to pay for the premium service to use Time Slip feature to watch past live events.
- Shows or events streamed on YouTube

  I only know of [GA Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/GABunkoCH) by GA Bunko which fits into this category, and the show is more or less an advertisement of new light novels and some interaction with the seiyuu. In this case, the shows are free to stream from YouTube.